# Is it standard behavior that the C compiler reads the tab character in a string literal?

Tags: c, string

I know that `\t` is for the tab character in C string and character literals. But I have some auto-generated code that copies the tab characters directly without converting them to `\t` into string literals, which will soon be handled as part of a C program. The result seems to be okay; gcc reads the hard tab as hard tab. I was just wondering if this is also a standard compliant or guaranteed behavior.

Comment: Why don't you fix your generator to insert an explicit `'\t'` instead?

Comment: I sometimes do look in and fix some minor details in the auto-generated part. And.. it just looks better with real tabs :)

Comment: Read the standard: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5 So no, it is not portable. Follow @iharob s advise. "unction follows design" is a very bad idea normally and in programming even more.

Comment: It's generated code, it doesn't need to look nice. And if you care about (*I think it's actually nice to care about niceness*), replace the tabs with spaces and that should work.

Comment: @Olaf I understand. But just left as a side question, following the link you've provided, `s-char` is defined as 'any member of the source character set except the double-quote, backslash, or new-line character'. So shouldn't the hard tab be okay to be in a string literal?

Comment: @xiver77: And the source character set is - which?? And the target character set is??

Comment: @Olaf I may still have misunderstood the sentences, but here's my quote. 'Both the basic source and basic execution character sets shall have the following members: (...) the space character, and control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab, and form feed'.

Comment: A tab is (char)9 in the ASCII character set.  Excessively few reasons left today to fear EBCDIC, if the machine uses a weirdo encoding then you'd know it.  Don't look in the standard to make you feel good, only common sense applies.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR — There is no need to modify the code generator

According to the C11 standard — ISO/IEC 9899:2011:

> #### §6.4.5 **String literals**
>
> **Syntax**
>
> *string-literal:*
>     *encoding-prefix<sub>opt</sub>* `"` _s-char-sequence<sub>opt</sub> `"`
>
> *encoding-prefix:*
>     `u8`
>     `u`
>     `U`
>     `L`
>
> *s-char-sequence:*
>     *s-char*
>     *s-char-sequence s-char*
>
> *s-char:*
>     any member of the source character set except
>             the double-quote `"`, backslash `\`, or new-line character
>     *escape-sequence*

The *escape sequences* are codes such as `\"`, `\\`, `\t`, `\007` (does that ring a bell?), `\x7F`, etc.

If a literal (hard) tab is a member of the source character set, then a tab is allowed inside a string literal — but is it a member of the source character set?

> #### §5.2.1 Character sets
>
> ¶3 Both the basic source and basic execution character sets shall have the following members:
>
> *…alphabet, digits, C punctuation characters…*
>
> the space character, and control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab, and form feed.

The character under discussion is the horizontal tab; it is a required member of the basic source character set.  Therefore, it is allowed in a string literal without being required to be represented as `\t`.  Indeed, since any character in the source character set (not just the basic source character set) is allowed in a string literal, you could use other characters outside the basic source character set too and they're allowed.